# Java 8 Infinite Stream Output

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Below code creates empty Map `Stream` using `lambda expression` and the next line is used to output any element in the stream. But upon running the code it is giving infinite output. I don't know why because it should print `{}` once as the map is empty. Can someone explains what is going on?

```
 Stream<Map<String,String>> mapStream = Stream.generate(() -> {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    });
    mapStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: When you read the javadoc of `Stream#generate`, what didn't you understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation for `Stream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-)

> Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided `Supplier`. This is suitable for generating constant streams, streams of random elements, etc.

So you have an infinite stream, where each new element is created by calling the `Supplier`, if an empty map is represented as `{}` then you have a stream of:

```
{}, {}, {}, {} ...
```

---

What you are looking for is:

```
Stream.of(Collections.emptyMap()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which will print just `{}`. (although why you would want this is somewhat beyond me...)

Answer (score 2):

This is what the documentation says about [`Stream.generate(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-):

> Returns an **infinite** sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided `Supplier`. This is suitable for generating constant streams, streams of random elements, etc.

Comment: Additionaly: if you need stream with only one element (not infinite stream), try [Stream.of(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-).